# NUnit: Asserting that all items in a list is of one value

Tags: nunit

Is there a method in Nunit that asserts that all items in a list is of one value, and one value only?

Currently I'm using

```
        var doubleListHashSet= new HashSet<double>(myDoubleList);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, doubleListHashSet.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(theSingleValue, doubleListHashSet.First());
```

But I can't help but think that NUnit has this built-in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Assert.That(myDoubleList, Has.All.EqualTo(theSingleValue));
```

If you explore the constraint-based fluent syntax you'll find several other ways to do it, but that one seems clearest to me.